# Jquery multidirectional scroll glitching

Tags: jquery, scroll

I have built a multi-directional scroll that works great on my local environment.  However, on a live server, with the delay of loading images, it appears to glitch out.  I've attempted to add a delay to one of the processes, but it still appears to glitch out occasionally.  Suggestions would be welcome.

http://jsfiddle.net/syphwb4c/12/

```
var scrolledright = parseInt($(".right").scrollTop());

$(".left").on("scroll", function () {
    var scrolledleft = parseInt($(".left").scrollTop()) * -1;
    $(".right").scrollTop(scrolledleft + scrolledright)
});

$(".right").on("scroll", function () {
    var scrolledleft = parseInt($(".right").scrollTop()) * -1;
    $(".left").scrollTop(scrolledleft + scrolledright)
});    

function rightscroll() {     
  var scrolltopper = $(".right .inner").height();
  $(".right").scrollTop(scrolltopper);
};

setTimeout(rightscroll, 500);
```

Comment: How is this suposed to work?

Comment: [Try to control the flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming))

Comment: If you scroll in one box, the opposite box is supposed to scroll in the opposite direction.